# Installing Cantera 2.1 on OSx 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, osx-mavericks, scons, cantera

to install cantera 2.1 on my macbook pro I am following the procedure from Bok Jik Lee recently posted on his blog: 
[Installing Cantera 2.1 on OSx 10.9 Mavericks](http://boklee.blogspot.de/2014/01/building-cantera-21-on-osx-109-mavericks.html)

Everything worked fine till now but I get an error when I come to point 9: "Install Cantera"

after changing the current location to the canters-2.1 folder I was typing

`scons build prefix='/usr/local/opt/cantera' python_compiler='clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7' sundials_include='/usr/local/opt/sundials/2.5.0/include' sundials_libdir='/usr/local/opt/sundials/2.5.0/lib'`

the commands work until I get the following error:

`ld: library not found for -lgfortran`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

`scons: *** [build/lib/libcantera_shared.dylib] Error 1`

`scons: building terminated because of errors.`

The last line before this error is the following:

`build/src/clib/ctxml.os -Lbuild/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sundials/2.5.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sundials/2.5.0/lib -lgfortran -lsundials_cvodes -lsundials_ida -lsundials_nvecserial -framework Accelerate`

So scons terminated... did I forget to install something? What can I do?

Cheers,

Matthias

P.s.: I am a pretty new mac user - so these are my first experiences using the terminal and all these commands...

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a problem with `SCons`, rather the compiler cannot find the `gfortran` library. Step 2 in the link you provided shows how to install `gfortran`. Have you successfully completed this step?

If so, where is it installed? It may be that the SCons build scripts arent correctly specifying the path to the `gfortran` lib. The library paths are passed to the compiler via the `-L` compiler flags. So, if you know where the library is installed, make sure its path is correctly specified in the library path compiler flags. If the library path is not correct, or missing, you can either modify the SCons scripts yourself, or consider writing some sort of a bug-report on the `Cantera` support site.

To modify the `SCons` build scripts yourself, you'll need to modify the `LIBPATH` construction variable, as can be seen [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a5025.html).

Comment: Hi Brady, thanks for your fast answer... Regarding your questions: I did install gfortran via http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-4.8.2-Mavericks.dmg <br/> However, it seems to be at the wrong location. I contacted Bok Jik Lee - the author of the instruction - he said that I should search for the right location of "libgfortran.a" and use then a link like: "-s /some/where/your/libgfortran.a  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a" <br/> Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: @user3313375, ok well you can either wait for them to fix it, or update the SCons build script to point to the new location as mentioned in my answer.